# School calls my daughter a ward

Tags: word-usage

In all school correspondences my daughter and all other students are being addressed as "Ward", "your Ward", e.g

> A parent survey form has been sent through your Ward. Please fill.

Is the school correct in doing so? My daughter is biological and we are parents and not guardians. Is this the correct academic way?

Comment: It's not wrong but it does seem a bit sterile.  *Student* seems like an appropriate word that still covers all bases.  What *is* wrong is the capitalization of *ward.* As a simple noun, it requires no capitalization in your sentences.  It's also worth commenting on the fact they they apparently went to great lengths finding the word *ward* but then used the word *parent* in *parent survey*.  By rights, they should have used *guardian survey*.

Comment: @Jim: In the UK, schools tend to use the word "parent" all the time when they *ought* to use "guardian". For example, *parent's evening* and *parental permission*. Maybe they should change, but my guess is that most guardians don't mind enough to complain, so long as they are *technically* and *legally* (if not *lexically*) treated the same.

Comment: To me this seems like an (inelegant) attempt to use an all-encompassing term.

Comment: A little Googling suggests that this is a fairly common usage on the websites of Indian primary and secondary schools. It usually appears in a context of an English even further removed from the ordinary academic standard than the English found on the websites of most US primary and secondary schools.

Comment: @StoneyB, yes it has always been used by Indian schools but in the past, appropriately e.g Son/Daughter/ward but it seems that they have now adopted ward as their term to address all children. Makes me uncomfortable, that's all to it - thanks all

Comment: @Matt This is true in the US as well. I think what Jim was pointing out is that it's odd that they take such care to use *ward* instead of *child*, but then use *parent* instead of *guardian* (the pairs don't match).

Comment: Usually in schools (or at least in my own school board,OCDSB) they send home the new permission forms saying child/ward. They used to put son/daughter but I guess some people were complaining that the child under their care is not biologically theirs and blah blah blah. And they have always, as far as I'm concerned, put Dear Parent/Guardian,. I don't understand why they do it like this but they should just stick to one way. I don't understand but my parents have never mentioned anything about it. But I think most parents don't actually read the forms thoroughly enough to notice.

Comment: Excellent question (+1). I've been searching for the answer since quite long. @StoneyB is right. Indian schools use this even today (my daughter's school does!). When asked, they are clueless!

Comment: According to my (very old) Concise Oxford Dictionary, A ward is simply somebody of something that you have a responsibility to watch over. I would say that's a fair description of of child, regardless of whether you are a parent, guardian, teacher or whatever form of responsible adult you can think of. Recently the specific legal meaning has taken over, which is a pity.

Answer (score 7):

Officially every *minor* or other person without *legal capacity* must have a *guardian*, and in said relation remains a *ward* of that guardian. Now, the *guardian* may a biological parent, adoptive parent, a caretaker of institution where the person remains, or any other such entity. This is the legal position. It's extremely dry but if the school wants to remain completely proper e.g. in relation to orphans who have only legal caretakers, but no parents, they might try to use the phrase *guardian*, and respectively *ward*. Of course if they use *parent's ward*, they are simply making a mess of it, trying and failing to sound professional.

Comment: It might help if you clarified where this was the legal position. Laws vary quite a lot around the world so there is really no such thing as "the" legal position.